# A Question on the bijection between ideal sheaf and closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\mathcal{I}$,$\mathcal{J}$ are two quasi-coherent ideal sheaf on scheme $X$,  why can't they determine the same closed subscheme? I read about this in EGA I.4.1.4. In the context, it argued if $\mathcal{I}$,$\mathcal{J}$ have same support $Y$, and the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}$, then it is immediate to know $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{J}$. It looked like five lemma, but I think there is not a natural map from $\mathcal{I}$ to $\mathcal{J}$ making the diagram commute. Is there? Or how should we argue?

Comment: What does $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}$ mean in the context? I think it is not saying that they are isomorphic (different closed embeddings from a same scheme can have same set-theoretic image), but they are isomorphic via the quotient of the identity map of $\mathcal{O}_X$, so of course $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{J}$.

Comment: I see, they are isomorphic via the identity map, that is the point, thanks